Uptrace span is missing nodeJS
I've never used uptrace with nodeJS. Here is a function. I am getting span is missing. Do I have to use startActiveSpan for all cases?
@log(logger)
  async updatePosition({ key, liquidate = false, marketInfo }: { key: string; liquidate?: boolean; marketInfo?: any }) {
    return await tracer.startActiveSpan('updatePosition', async span => {
      let position;
      try {
         position = await this.positionService.getPosition(key);
        if (position.addresses.account == ethers.constants.AddressZero) {
          this.logger.info(`updatePosition:${key}:skipped ✅`);
          await this.positionService.removePositionKeyFromCache(key);
          this.logger.info(`Tracer: ${uptrace.traceUrl(span)}`);
          span.setAttribute('status', 'skipped');
          span.end();
          return position;
        }

In this part I tried using span to benchmark specific block of code but these are not recognized.
        const usePositionInfoSpan = tracer.startSpan('usePositionInfoSpan');
        const positionsInfoData = await this.positionService.usePositionInfo({ key, marketInfo, position });
        usePositionInfoSpan.end();
        .......

        this.logger.info(`updatePosition:${key}:success ✅`);
        span.addEvent(`updatePosition:${key}:success ✅`);

        const failedLiquidationKeySpan = tracer.startSpan('failedLiquidationKeySpan');
        const failed = await this.redisService.get(
          liquidateFailedKey({
            account: addresses.account,
            market: addresses.market,
            collateralToken: addresses.collateralToken,
            isLong: isLong,
          }),
        );
        failedLiquidationKeySpan.end();
        if (liquidate && isPositionLiquidatable && !failed) {
          const addExecuteLiquidationJobSpan = tracer.startSpan('addExecuteLiquidationJobSpan');
          await this.addExecuteLiquidationJob({
            account: addresses.account,
            market: addresses.market,
            collateralToken: addresses.collateralToken,
            isLong: isLong,
          });
          addExecuteLiquidationJobSpan.end();
          this.logger.info(`added:executeLiquidation:${key} ✅`);
          span.addEvent(`added:executeLiquidation:${key} ✅`);
        }
        position = positionsInfoData;
        this.logger.info(`Tracer: ${uptrace.traceUrl(span)}`);
      } 
      catch (error) {
        this.logger.error(`updatePosition:${key}:failed ❌`);
        position = error;
        this.logger.info(`Tracer: ${uptrace.traceUrl(span)}`);
        span.end();
      }
      finally {
        this.logger.info(`Tracer: ${uptrace.traceUrl(span)}`);
        span.end();
      }
      return position;
    });
  }


I tried following the official doc but my lack of knowledge on JS is failing me.
This is what the trace looks like (span is missing)

